# Image Layout (Variable Width, Equal Height per row)

Tags: css, image, flexbox, grid

I am trying to create a grid layout where the images auto resize to be the same height but different width to evenly fit on a line.

Currently I have this: [image: Layout]

But as you can see that does not make the images fit correctly.

```
<style>
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.masonry {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.masonry--h {
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.masonry--h {
  margin-left: -8px; 
  /* counter-reset: brick;*/
}

.masonry-brick {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0 0 8px 8px; 
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

.masonry-brick:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 5000;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: font-size .25s, opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  font-weight: 700;
  opacity: .5;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}

.masonry-brick:hover:after {
  font-size: 2.25em;
  opacity: 1;
}



.masonry-img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
}
</style>
```

I am trying to make something like the photo below, but I have no idea how.

[image: Style I want]